# Expecting top level declaration error while running my code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have written this code and an error occurs while running the program

> Expecting top level declaration

near the keyword extends and 87 other places. Also it shows keywords such as int, float as not recognised.

The complete code:

```
package com.example.exno1

import android.graphics.Color
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    int ch=1
    float font=30
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        finalTextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)
        Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
        b1.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            Public void onClick(View v) {
                t.setTextSize(font)
                font = font + 5
                if(font == 50)
                    font = 30
            }
        })
        Button b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2)
        b2.setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(ch) {
                    case 1:
                    t.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                    break
                    case 2:
                    t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
                    break
                    case 3:
                    t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                    break
                    case 4:
                    t.setTextColor(Color.CYAN)
                    break
                    case 5:
                    t.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                    break
                    case 6:
                    t.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA)
                    break
                }
                ch++
                if(ch == 7)
                    ch = 1
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget semicolons?

Answer (score 4):

It is *Java*. You forgot semicolons `;`

Answer (score 0):

This same problem happened with me lots of time when we are dealing  with multiple languages like Java and Kotlin. Simply add `;`.

Comment: I added semicolons and still the same error exists.